# What does allocation rate means in JMH

Tags: java, garbage-collection, microbenchmark, jmh

I'm trying to measure the memory consumed when running the benchmark. I found out on the internet that I can use `GC` profiler to measure that. I tried but I don't understand the answer as well as see the amount of consumed memory. Can anyone explain the results? Thanks.

```
MyBenchmark.testMethod_width_2_attribute_text                                     ss   60        32.345 ±       1.759   ms/op
MyBenchmark.testMethod_width_2_attribute_text:·gc.alloc.rate                      ss   60        26.904 ±       0.217  MB/sec
MyBenchmark.testMethod_width_2_attribute_text:·gc.alloc.rate.norm                 ss   60  14999630.400 ±      12.578    B/op
MyBenchmark.testMethod_width_2_attribute_text:·gc.churn.PS_Eden_Space             ss   60        28.282 ±      15.342  MB/sec
MyBenchmark.testMethod_width_2_attribute_text:·gc.churn.PS_Eden_Space.norm        ss   60  15903402.667 ± 8631257.013    B/op
MyBenchmark.testMethod_width_2_attribute_text:·gc.churn.PS_Survivor_Space         ss   60         0.654 ±       0.754  MB/sec
MyBenchmark.testMethod_width_2_attribute_text:·gc.churn.PS_Survivor_Space.norm    ss   60    368914.667 ±  425374.152    B/op
MyBenchmark.testMethod_width_2_attribute_text:·gc.count                           ss   60        26.000                counts
MyBenchmark.testMethod_width_2_attribute_text:·gc.time                            ss   60       105.000                    ms
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under covers, jmh uses `ThreadMXBean` so this looks like a report that says how many bytes per operation are allocated and how many `MB/sec` in each GC space (like `Eden/Survivor`)

`.norm` stands for normalized.

Comment: Some questions:
1. What doe PS stand for in `PS_Eden_Space`?
2. What is `gc.count`? The number of times the garbage collector was invoked?
3. What is `gc.time`? The total time taken by the garbage collector over all its invocations?

Comment: Regarding the prefix: `PS` stands for `Parallel Scavenge`. It is the name of your garbage collector and it means you are using the GC `-XX:+UseParallelGC`. If you specify `-XX:+UseParNewGC` JVM argument, then the prefix will become `Par` and with `-XX:+UseG1GC` it will be `G1`

Comment: The `count` and `time` are the number of garbage collections that were executed during a jmh iteration and the total time the jvm spent on these garbage collections.

They are actually the between- and after- jmh iteration differences of `java.lang.management.GarbageCollectorMXBean` 's `getCollectionCount()` and `getCollectionTime()`. You can read these methods' javadoc for more information

Comment: The `.norm` fields indeed stand for `normalized` and correspond to the relevant metric but divided by the number of jmh operations. So if you ran a jmh iteration which invoked 1,000 operations (i.e. your test method), then e.g. `·gc.alloc` (not reported) would be the size of memory allocated during that iteration, `·gc.alloc.rate` would be the memory allocated per unit of time (second or millisecond) and `·gc.alloc.rate.norm` the memory allocated per operation. This last one should give you an idea of how much new memory gets allocated by your code (i.e. your "operation")